# EventListener not working in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, eventhandler

For my pages I use a function, after a route change set the page to top `scrollTo(0, 0);`.

On those pages I add a css class to my header when scrolling down 100px:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = () => {
      if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
        fade(true);
      } else {
        setFade(false);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
  }, []);
```

When I open a certain modal (page) the `scrollTo(0, 0);` is disabled for those modal-pages because if I close the modal (and go back to previous page) I want to be on the same position on the page where I came from.

Now I have to add the same css class to the header of this modal. I can't use the `window` object now.

I tried the following but that's not working yet:

```
const Overlay = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const [fade, setFade] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // const element = document.getElementById('overlayHeader');
    const element = document.documentElement;
    const prevTopOffset = element?.scrollTop;
    console.log(prevTopOffset);

    const scrolledOffset = prevTopOffset + 50;
    console.log(scrolledOffset);

    const onScroll = () => {
      if (prevTopOffset > scrolledOffset) {
        fade(true);
      } else {
        setFade(false);
      }
    };

    element.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    return () => element.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Dialog fullScreen open={open} id="dialog">
        <header
          id="overlayHeader"
          css={fade && styles.fadedIn}
        >
        </header>
        {children}
      </Dialog>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Overlay;
```

Somehow the EventListner is not added/working? How do I get this working?

Comment: Try to clear the const.

Answer (score 0):

something that I did that worked:

```js
 const Quote = () => {
      
      const quotes = [// some logic // ]

      const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0)

      useEffect(() => {
       const timer = window.setInterval(() => {

      setActiveIndex(prev =>
        
        prev + 1 >= quotes.length ? 0 : prev + 1
      )
    }, 5000)

// return a cleanup callback that will stop the timer
    return () => {
      window.clearInterval(timer)
    }
  }, [quotes])
```

I dont know how its works in your case, but I hope I have helped in something.